# Unable to start postgresql.service?

Tags: postgresql, archlinux, systemd

I'm using arch linux (4.8.13-1-ARCH). I'm trying to set up PostgreSQL as instructed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL).

After performing

```
[postgres@BitBox ~]$ initdb --locale $LANG -E UTF8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgres/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/data -l logfile start
```

successfully, I returned to the my regular user using exit command.

```
[postgres@BitBox ~]$ exit
logout
```

Then, while trying to start postgresql.service, I got the following error:

```
[code_master5@BitBox ~]$ sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
Failed to start postgresql.service: Unit postgresql.service not found.
```

I'm not even getting the status of the service:

```
[code_master5@BitBox ~]$ sudo systemctl status postgresql.service
Unit postgresql.service could not be found.
```

I'm stuck!

Comment: What command or commands did you use to install postgresql?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally, I figured this one out. There was already a file present

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.6.service
```

So, may be due to the presence of this file, I was not able to start postgresql.service. Then I tried to start postgresql-9.6.service as follows:

```
[code_master5@BitBox ~]$ sudo systemctl start postgresql-9.6.service
Failed to start postgresql-9.6.service: Unit postgresql-9.6.service not found.
```

And, as you can see the output, again it failed.

I simply deleted the file using sudo as I thought may be postgresql.service file is not being created by relevant program due to the presence of this file. Then I restarted the system. It's working fine since then, as you can see the output below:

```
[code_master5@BitBox ~]$ sudo systemctl status postgresql.service
[sudo] password for code_master5: 
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor p
Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-01-28 09:31:30 IST; 7h ago
Main PID: 342 (postgres)
Tasks: 6 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
       ├─342 /usr/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgres/data
       ├─358 postgres: checkpointer process   
       ├─359 postgres: writer process   
       ├─360 postgres: wal writer process   
       ├─361 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
       └─362 postgres: stats collector process   

Jan 28 09:31:26 BitBox systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Jan 28 09:31:28 BitBox postgres[340]: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
Jan 28 09:31:28 BitBox postgres[340]: LOG:  database system was shut down at 201
Jan 28 09:31:29 BitBox postgres[340]: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
Jan 28 09:31:29 BitBox postgres[340]: LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protecti
Jan 28 09:31:29 BitBox postgres[340]: LOG:  database system is ready to accept c
Jan 28 09:31:29 BitBox postgres[340]: LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
Jan 28 09:31:30 BitBox systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL database server.
```

I would surely like to warn all those having same problem. Please do whatever I did at your own risk. Since these are system files. Messing with these can spoil your weekend!

I am still a bit confused on this though. Explanations are welcome!

Answer (score 34):

Try this:

```
service postgresql-10.service restart
service postgresql-XX.service restart
```

Comment: OP seems to be using RHEL7 or CentOS7, as indicated by the systemctl commands. If so, the service ... restart commands won't work.

Comment: For Manjaro Linux / ArchLinux: `systemctl restart postgresql.service`

Answer (score 13):

I found these two commands very handy. Although this post is old, maybe others will be benefited from this in the future.

```
systemctl list-units|grep postgresql
service postgresql-12.service restart
```

Answer (score 2):

For PostGres 9.4.12, I tried the following and it worked:

```
./pg_ctl start
```

You can check the status of it:

```
./pg_ctl status
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this command:

```
$ /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is hold, but for some people that might pass by, I found the solution being this (not deleting sys file but just reload the daemon after installation to update service file) :

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload # load the updated service file from disk
$ sudo systemctl enable postgresql
$ sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

Next steps helped me on our test server.

Connect your server via SSH.

Then switch user:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
```

Check Postgres status:

```
pg_ctl status
```

Stop DB:

```
pg_ctl stop
```

Check if no server processes exist:

```
ps axf|grep postg
```

Start Postgres service:

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

Then check status:

```
systemctl status postgresql.service
```

OR

```
systemctl status postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to initialise the database.

sudo find / -name post*-setup
sudo /usr/bin/postgresql-setup initdb