# 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' not working in Django 3.0

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to migrate an app from Django 1.8 and Python 2 to Python 3.6 and Django 3.0.

Whenever I am adding `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2`, and installing it via pip3 I am getting this error:

> _psycopg2 module not found.

I looked at the documentation, and I see that in Django 3.0 _psycopg2 is removed. How can I resolve this issue? My previous app is running psycopg 2.6.1.

Comment: Incompatible chances between Django releases are well documented, as well as [the whole migration process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/upgrade-version/)

Answer (score 13):

The correct setting to use in Django 3.0 is `'django.db.backends.postgresql'`.

From the [Django deprecation timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-3-0):

> The django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 module will be removed.

This particular module has actually been [deprecated since Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.0/#id1):

> The django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 module is deprecated in
>   favor of django.db.backends.postgresql. It’s been an alias since
>   Django 1.9. This only affects code that imports from the module
>   directly. The DATABASES setting can still use
>   'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', though you can simplify that
>   by using the 'django.db.backends.postgresql' name added in Django 1.9.

From the [databases docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes), it looks like your version of `psycopg2` should be supported, as you need 2.5.4 or higher.

Comment: Yeh I did that, And I installed Postgres. but when I run my app I get django.db.utils.OperationalError Could not connect to server
 on port 5432 . this is first time am creating an app. and I still couldn't run it.

Comment: That sounds like a completely distinct problem from the question you posted. You should include all information in your question so that it's clear what your actual problem is. Have you looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29937378/9374673) with respect to not being able to connect to Postgres from Django?

Comment: I checked that one, and it didn't help. I am trying the command they given service postgresql status it keeps giving me Postgres.service no found

Comment: I'm really not sure how to solve that issue, but I'm sure this has been asked before, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41867841/9374673). See what else you can try, and if that doesn't resolve it, post a new question with the information you gave me here, ideally a full traceback of the error you're getting and what you've tried so far, and hopefully someone will be able to solve your problem. I did my best to answer your question here based on the information you provided, but it seems you have issues with Postgres itself, which has nothing to do with Django.